# How to know when a fragment comes from a popup

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have two fragments, A and B. Before, A and B were both top level and when I wanted to move from one to the other, I would use something like

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, BFragment.newInstance(), B_TAG)
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
                .commit();
```

Now the client wants that from B, hitting the back button, the app goes to A, so I needed to make B a child of A and therefore the transition looks like

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, BFragment.newInstance(), B_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

and from B to A

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

The problem is that if the user changes something in B, A still has the old data.

Is there a way of knowing that I arrived at A by clicking the "back" button and poping it from the backstack so I can refresh the data?

Also, do you see a better way of handling the movement between these two fragments?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the common data either:

- In a singleton that handles persistent state in the application if that data can be of interest withing the whole application
- In a data fragment (a fragment without any UI) that each of your UI fragments can access and change the data.

Then in each UI fragment, you can update the views when resuming the fragments.